# how to add an attribute to XML node?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, xml-attribute

if (child is WinCRLFTextArea) {
                            var node:XML;

```
                        node = <{child.name}>{WinCRLFTextArea(child).text}</{child.name}>;
                        textXML.appendChild(node);
                    }
```

I want to add an attribute like "beginIndex" and "endIndex" to node element. dynamically i need to assign values to this attributes. 
ex: beginIndex = WinCRLFTextArea(child).text.length 
is it possible ? please anyone help me out for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add/edit/read attributes with the ”@” operator.

```
var myXML:XML = <xml> <some> <node/> </some> </xml>;

myXML.some.node.@beginIndex = "1";

trace( myXML.some.node.@beginIndex ); // output: 1;
```

Comment: I have tried like this "node.{child.name}.@beginIndex = 0;" but it showed error as "Access of undefined property beginIndex node"... How to proceed further ?Thanks...

Comment: I don't completely understand the usage of the {} brackets here. I guess you are trying to use the mxml databinding inside a script clock? This is not going to work. in e4x ( the set of instructions you can use for xml processing in actionscript) you would have to use normal () brackets. You can read more about e4x here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html

Comment: Generally, I would a) create an event handler to notice when child.name changes. b) write the value to a `var myNameVar:String` and call your if block c) in that block use your var like this `node.(name()==myNameVar).@beginIndex="1";`But that is strictly spoken not part of your original question, so please don't forget to accept ;)